# How to kill a program after it's executed from a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, scripts

I have made a script that plays audio using ffplay directly onto the terminal. Now after it's executed I am unable to stop the sound without specifically killing it through the terminal or System Monitor.
What I am trying to do is to specify an argument, say `audio.sh stop` to kill the PID and stop the audio.
But I am unable to do so by simply

```
PID=$$
elif [[ $# == 1 ]] && [[ $1 == 'stop' ]]; then
         kill ${PID}
```

I got the problem here, that after running this with the stop argument it will create another instance of the script and then kill it instantly.
So, is there some way to do that?
Here is my full code.

```
  1 folder=<folder path>
  2 
  3 PID=$$
  4 
  5 if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then 
  6         RANDOM=$$
  7         for i in `seq 1`
  8         do
  9                 R=$(($(($RANDOM%53))+1))
 10                 file=${folder}${R}.mp3
 11                 ffplay -nodisp -autoexit ${file} >/dev/null 2>&1 &
 12         done
 13 elif [[ $# == 1 ]]; then
 14         file=${folder}${1}.mp3
 15         ffplay -nodisp -autoexit ${file} >/dev/null 2>&1 &
 16 elif [[ $# == 1 ]] && [[ $1 == 'stop' ]]; then
 17         kill ${PID}
 18 fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To kill all instances of `ffplay`, replace:

```
kill ${PID}
```

with:

```
pkill ffplay
```

This will make your life much simpler.

Comment: I am speechless after seeing your answer. Actually, literally 2 mins before checking this website I came up with my solution for this problem and was so happy. Then I saw your ultra-efficient answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, by using ```pkill ffplay``` it will kill all the instances of ```ffplay``` at the same time. That can be sometimes unwanted.

Comment: @Prab-mat That's a good point. On my machine my application is the only one using `ffplay`. Killing all occurrences is an advantage if my Python program crashes during development I can kill all occurrences at once.

Comment: I used this, then, to kill every instance one by one.
 ```pid=`ps aux | grep ".*The_Enchiridion" | tail -2 | awk '{print $2}'`
     kill $pid 2> /dev/null```
It works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, as suggested by [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413743/1594606) using `pkill`, would kill all the instances of the `ffplay` all at once.
A rather one-by-one approach I found is to kill the most recent instance one at a time by using `pidof ffplay`, this will return all the PIDs of `ffplay` currently running (latest first). So, using the command `pidof ffplay | awk '{print $1}'` we can extract the PID of the latest instance of `ffplay` and kill it.

Edit 1:
As @iyrin suggested in the comments, we can use `pidof -s ffplay` to get the PID of the latest instance of ffplay directly without using pipes.

Comment: Testing in cli, the default separator for each pid is a space. So `head` prints all of the pid because it is on a single line. That said, `pidof -s ffplay` should retrieve first pid in the list. If you need a full list of them on separate lines `pidof -d $'\n ' ffplay ` and then pipe it to the head command.

Comment: Oh... actually i wrote wrong here. In the script I wrote ```awk '{print $1}'``` and that's why it worked ig. But this is a better way to use this command. Thanks for suggesting it!